# How to let users use OAuth in their Instagram app?

Tags: reactjs, instagram, instagram-api

I see there're some questions in this topic exist but they are pretty old (5+ years ago). I am just asking this again to see if there's a way to let my users log in via OAuth from their installed Instagram app instead of sending them to a new URL.

I am using React.js so it would be the best if there's a way that could be compatible for React. I am using Instagram Basic Display by the way.